# Swift Generics & Protocols

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to build a generic 'NSFetchResultsController'-like set of protocols in swift so that I might isolate my `UITableViewDataSource/UICollectionViewDataSource` implementations from any specifics about where and how the data is being sourced and updated.

So I began with a couple of simple definitions of the core controller and sections thus:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

public protocol ResultsSection {
    typealias T

    var numberOfObjects : Int { get }
    var objects : [T] { get }

    subscript(index: Int) -> T? { get }
}

public protocol ResultsController {

    typealias ResultsSection
    typealias T

    var resultsSections : [ResultsSection] { get }

    subscript(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> T? { get }
}
```

Following this a couple of simple implementations just holding everything in arrays thus:

```
class SimpleResultsSection<T> : ResultsSection {

    private(set) var objects : [T]

    init(objects: [T]?) {
        self.objects = objects ?? [T]()
    }

    var numberOfObjects : Int {
        get {
            return objects.count
        }
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> T? {

        return objects.count > index ? objects[index] : nil
    }
}

class SimpleResultsController<T, RS: ResultsSection where T == RS.T> : ResultsController {

    internal(set) var resultsSections = [RS]()

    subscript(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> T? {

        if resultsSections.count > indexPath.section {
            let section = resultsSections[indexPath.section]
            return section[indexPath.row]
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    init(singleSectionObjects: [T]) {
        let section = SimpleResultsSection(objects: singleSectionObjects)
        resultsSections.append(section)
    }
}
```

Now on the last line of code where I try to append a `SimpleResultsSection<T>` to `self.resultsSections` the compiler denies me with:

`Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type (SimpleResultsSection<T>)`

What have I missed here?

I thought that `<T, RS: ResultsSection where T == RS.T>` would mean that the compiler would be able to resolve `SimpleResultsSection<T>` to an `RS` and thus allow me to `append` a `SimpleResultsSection<T>` to an `[RS]`, but clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. What is "sections" in the last line? There is no such term anywhere. Please post your _real_ code.

Comment: Well I can't find the definition of `append` in your code snipped.

Comment: Also you are omitting the fact that `resultsSections > indexPath.section` doesn't compile either. You need to fix that too.

Comment: thanks @matt ... fixed those. I had a version in my project and one in a Playground and the copy/paste all went a bit pear shaped. I've fixed those.

Comment: @JózsefVesza `append` is on the array `resultsSections `, now that I've fixed it.

Comment: The Type parameter of resultsSections is different, than the one on your section variable. That's why you can't append it.

Comment: @JózsefVesza Doesn't `<T, RS: ResultsSection where T == RS.T>` resolve this?

Comment: The T of Array is not the T of SimpleResultsController, if that's what you're hoping...

Comment: @matt yes that what I was hoping `where T == RS.T` would achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not making as strong-enough promise here:

```
internal(set) var resultsSections = [RS]()
```

This only promises that the array is full of `ResultsSection where T == RS.T`, but that could be a completely unrelated class. Swift arrays are not covariant in that way. If they were, you to treat `[Apple]` as `[Fruit]` and then `append(orange)`.

What you want here is:

```
internal(set) var resultsSections = [SimpleResultsSection<T>]()
```

That's a stronger promise that all of the elements inherit from the same class, while still respecting your earlier protocol promise that it could be read as `[ResultSection]`.

That said, I would do it a bit differently. Unless you really need `SimpleResultsController` to be able to accept multiple types of sections, I would force that with a typealias rather than parameterizing it:

```
class SimpleResultsController<T> : ResultsController {
    internal(set) var resultsSections = [SimpleResultsSection<T>]()
    ...
```

This way, the type is `SimpleResultsController<Int>` rather than `SimpleResultsController<Int, SimpleResultsSection<Int>>` (which is a very cumbersome type).

The system can infer the type of `ResultsSection` from the definition of `resultsSection`, so there's no need to `typealias` it if you don't want to (though it can be handy to do that for clarity).

Comment: thanks so much for this. I'll go with you advise and force resultsSection to be `[SimpleResultsSection<T>]`. Cheers.